# General Error [50000-174] and [50000-176] caused by NullPointerException and JdbcSQLException

Tags: h2

I am running H2 1.3.176 as a server and H2 1.3.174 as a client. Recently I was having trouble with database responsiveness. After restarting both the server and client, using the "Test Connection" button in the client led to a long pause and then this stack trace.

```
General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-174] HY000/50000 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-176]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:294)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:291)
at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:254)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:57)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:164)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:142)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:125)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:150)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.h2.store.PageStore.removeMeta(PageStore.java:1642)
at org.h2.store.PageStore.redo(PageStore.java:1565)
at org.h2.store.PageStore.redoDelete(PageStore.java:1550)
at org.h2.store.PageLog.recover(PageLog.java:347)
at org.h2.store.PageStore.recover(PageStore.java:1407)
at org.h2.store.PageStore.openExisting(PageStore.java:368)
at org.h2.store.PageStore.open(PageStore.java:289)
at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2366)
at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:657)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:260)
... 7 more

at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:589)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:128)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:413)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:305)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:656)
at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.test(WebApp.java:844)
at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:219)
at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:168)
at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:138)
at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am using [this code](http://vadim-kirilchuk-linux.blogspot.com/2012/10/h2-database-as-linux-service.html) to run the server as a daemon. Any ideas? Googling didn't find me any references to this as a known bug.

Comment: What is your database URL?

Comment: It's jdbc:h2:tcp://specialserver/yummy.

Comment: What I would try is disable `"SET MULTI_THREADED 1"`. In the past, this caused problems. In the future it will be supported, but in past and current versions it may not work correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Will give that a shot in the future.